# Do these IP addresses belong to robots?

Tags: web-crawlers

When i check the traffic on my website, the top IP's have have statistics like this.

```
> IP           Page       Hits

> 91.212.x.x   7123        7123

> 91.x.x.x      249        249
```

These visits are for one month. Since the number of pages match number of hits, does it mean these IPs belong to robots? And how it can be the same? I do have pages which have does not have images which will give one hit but still. How it can occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the IP addresses in your logs probably belong to bots.

If the bot is set to only download html, and not request any other resources (javascript, images, etc), each page view will correspond to a single hit.

Most bots (indexing spiders, screen-scrapers, vulnerability hunters) will only be interested in the HTML, so this looks like typical bot behaviour.

Comment: +1 though you seem to mean [web scrapers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) versus [screen scrapers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screen_scraper#Screen_scraping) (which would necessarily download images at least once)

Comment: Indeed - web scrapers. I've never heard the origins of the term 'screen scraper' before, but it makes perfect sense.